# How to relative import a package create by me using python and strucure it better?

Tags: python, import, package, structure, init

Hi I'm creating a package/Module (hysysview), I have created some tests so that I can test the packages, therefore I need to import the module, however, I'm getting this error when I import HysysCOM.py in testHysys.py

**Importing in testHysys**

```
import sys
import os
from hysysview.HysysCOM import HysysReader
from enum import Enum
```

**Error:**

```
 line 3, in <module>
    from ..hysysview.HysysCOM import HysysReader
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

**Folder tree**

```
 |-hysysview
 | |-HysysCOM.py
 | |-HysysOperations.py
 | |-HysysOperations_backup.py
 | |-HysysVariables.py
 | |-missingOperation.txt
 | |-__init__.py
 | |-__pycache__
 |-requirements.txt
 |-setup.py
 |-test
 | |-sampleApp
 | |-stored
 | |-test7.bat
 | |-test7.txt
 | |-test8.bat
 | |-test9.bat
 | |-testHysys.py
 | |-__init__.py
```

To run the test I call test16. in the terminal:

**test16.bat:**

```
python testHysys.py 16 > test16.txt

WinmergeU test16.txt ./stored/test16_stored.txt

timeout /t 100
```

**testHysys.py:**

```
.
.
.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    param = sys.argv[1]
    
    if int(param) == TestIdEnum.TEST_SETTING_VALUES.value: #12
        testSettingValues()
    if int(param) == TestIdEnum.TEST_OPERATIONS_NAMES_COLLECTOR.value: #14
        testgetAllOpetationsNames()
    if int(param) == TestIdEnum.TEST_GET_ANY_PROPERTY.value: #15
        testgetOperationPropertiesValues()
    if int(param) == TestIdEnum.TEST_GENERATE_JSON.value: #16
        testGenerateJson()
```

Tried to solve this issue using a setup.py file but I'm not very familiar with it!

if someone can give me some advice about how to solve this issue and also structure my packages better will be welcome

Thanks you in advance

Comment: How are you executing `testHysys.py`?

Comment: You are executing `testHysys.py` as a script, not a module. See https://peps.python.org/pep-0366/ for advice on using relative imports from a script.

Comment: The error that you show does not match the code that you show. Anyway, the key point here is that the leading `.`s in a relative import path refer to a **virtual package hierarchy, not** to the filesystem. `from .. import foo` **does not** mean "go into the parent folder of the current source code file and look for `foo.py` there". It can't mean that, because there are many other ways that a module could be represented - locating it doesn't necessarily involve traversing a filesystem, and loading it doesn't necessarily involve reading a `.py` file. Please see the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score -1):

include it in your **init**.py file

```
from .package import *
```

Answer (score -1):

Since `testHysys.py` is being executed as a script, not a module, you need to explicitly set the `__package__` variable so that the script knows how to resolve relative imports.

Something like

```
# In testHysys.py

if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
    __package__ = "hysysview"
```

See [PEP 366](https://peps.python.org/pep-0366/) for more details.